# Rich text edit control for C++?

Tags: c++, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I'm looking for a control to edit rich text.  These are my requirements:

1. Fast/lightweight
2. Support for bulleted/numbered lists
3. Colored text and highlighting
4. Targeting Windows, but cross-platform would be a bonus
5. Fine control over undo/redo and easy way to monitor what parts of the documents have changed
6. All the other usual features: text styles, copy/paste, etc.
7. Can easily be a subclassed and extended

I'm considering Qt's `QTextEDit`, but wanted to see if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: What is the problem with the windows Rich Edit control?

Comment: @Andreas item 4 says 'cross-platform' as a bonus; and item 7 is better served by an open-source solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first choice would be Qt.  From what I tested, it is the best toolkit around, and it is the only one I know that has all of your requirements.  My second choice would be [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxrichtextctrloverview.html#wxrichtextctrloverview), but I didn't like its architecture and API very much.